# Powerpoint - best size for a poster on a 55 inch monitor

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to display a scientific poster on a 55 inch television. Paper posters usually have A0 dimensions (84,1 x 118,9 cm).

The powerpoint template from the congress has a wide format with 33,867 cm and 19,05 cm. But since I know the screen will be 55 inches, wouldn't 121.7 cm and 68.6 cm more appropriate? Or don't it even matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't make it in centimetres, make it in pixels.
Digital images don't have dimensions in cm/in until they are printed. That's the only time it counts.

Depending on whether the TV is 4k or HD its screen area will be either 3840 x 2160 or 1920 x 1080 pixels. Both of these are 16:9 [widescreen] ratio, so if you make it for 4k it will scale fine to an HD TV.

Leave a 'safe' area containing no important information of maybe 100px to all edges of your overall image, to allow for any possible screen overscan.

See Microsoft's instructions for details - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-size-of-your-slides-040a811c-be43-40b9-8d04-0de5ed79987e

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Tetsujin's answer.

- **I.** Presentations are not designed initially for size, they are designed for proportion.

  You could assume that the monitor will have the most widely used 16:9 proportion, which implies that it will probably be horizontal. Still, many TV used as informational devices are vertical. And some vertical monitors have a different aspect ratio than 9:16. So confirm that.
- **II.** PowerPoint mainly use text and vector shapes, so, it is not that important if you define for example your document as FullHD resolution, and then it is played on a 4k display, as long as they have the same aspect ratio. The sharpness of the elements will adapt. Try to keep elements as vectors if possible.
- **III.** The raster images are dependent on the final resolution. But on a presentation, they are normally used for illustrative purposes. It is not that important that they are at the exact resolution (unless they contain important detailed and small information but this detailed information needs to be read up close, and that might not be the case of a public presentation anyway)
- **IV.** What you need to define is the size of the smaller elements, and this depends on the viewing distances. As this reacts proportionally, you can test your presentation moving away from your monitor to see the overall result.